# How pager guesses which page to bring it into the memory in demand paging?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

When a process is to be swapped in, the pager guesses which pages will be used before the  process is swapped out again. So pager will swap in only the desired pages. But how the pager will guess in advanced that these particular pages are required?

Comment: I don't think that the phrase "when a process is to be swapped in" relates to anything real. There isn't an external thing that decides "ohh, let's bring the process back in". It is the *process itself* that demands pages to be brought in by accessing pages that are swapped out. The pager can offer read-ahead for sequentially accessed large regions of memory. Some pagers might also keep a sparse co-residency matrix that helps predict what other pages might be needed when a particular page is resident. So, the premise of your question is fundamentally bad.

Comment: @KubaOber "It is the process itself that demands pages to be brought in by accessing pages that are swapped out. " but process cannot know which page would be needed as it would depend upon the option chosen by the user. If there are 4 sections in a process and user select only one section to execute how the process will know

Comment: Sure, the process doesn't need to know anything about the pages. But it knows the addresses of the code it executes and the data it needs. If those addresses happen to map to pages that are not resident in RAM, then a memory fault is triggered by the processor, and the pager is invoked to handle it. If you select a particular part in a process to execute, the process simply jumps to an address in its code. If that address isn't paged in, the pager will bring the page with that address into ram, and let the process resume. That's how it works.

Comment: @KubaOber "If you select a particular part in a process to execute, the process simply jumps to an address in its code. If that address isn't paged in, the pager will bring the page with that address into ram, and let the process resume" So there will be a valid/invalid bit within the page that will tell that whether the page has been brought into ram or not

Comment: Yes. That bit is kept in the [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table).

Comment: @KubaOber there is a lazy pager concept also. which pages in only the required pages.

Comment: You're presupposing that bringing pages in advance (predictively) is always the best strategy. Modern pagers take other things into consideration, too. For example, if the CPUs are oversubscribed and there's more runnable threads than available cores/hyperthreads, there's not much point to predictive page loading - more stuff can run than you can run anyway. Predictive page loading only makes sense if *at the moment* you're I/O bound, and specifically page-fault-bound. Page fault counts under oversubscribed CPU are immaterial.

Comment: You need to decide what the question is about. You're not clear at all. Are you asking about a particular kind of a pager, or how pagers work in general (offtopic), or what?

Comment: @KubaOber both the things are related i got my answers though.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently had the opportunity to implement a demand paging manager (DPM) for a small real-time OS.  I can not speak for what the big and fancy OSes do, but in the RTOS upon which I worked, it did not do any prediction/guessing.  The only "guessing" it did was that of trying to figure out which page it should evict in order to make room for a new page.

I needed a general purpose DPM--one that would work in any scenario.  I took a purely reactive approach; that is pages would be paged in in response to some event that demanded their presence (such as a page fault).  My DPM did not bother with the proactive approach (guessing which pages are required in advance).  I did this to avoid incurring the following penalties/costs:

1. Time to develop more complex code.
2. Time to execute the prediction algorithm.
3. Prediction miss penalties (loading data, saving data, and predicting the page)

Furthermore, a proactive approach would still require the reactive component (and its costs) just to handle prediction misses.  It was far more cost-effective to take the reactive approach.

Comment: so it is good to implement a pure demand paging concept where pages would be paged in  response to some event that demanded their presence. What kind of memory management scheme does OS like Windows or Linux based OS (Ubuntu) adopt or might be adopting.

Comment: @PrashantSharma - I do not know what kind scheme those OSes use.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't guess that. If there is demand paging, that means: it will bring into the memory, if it is needed (== a process wants to read it).

Although it were possible to use some type of heuristics to make it before the demand, practically it doesn't happen, because this type of memory could have a much better usage as well: it can be used to cache the last read/wrote disk blocks.

You use also a terminology: "process swapped in". Whole processes aren't swapped in/out in modern OSes, only their pages. In older times it happened that processes were swapped in/out as a whole, because the paging couldn't handle that at the time.

Comment: i mean to say that lets say a process is to be swapped in and now process will have pages and from those pages only required pages will be swapped in to the memory by the pager, now how the pager will guess the accurate required pages to bring in to memory.

Comment: @PrashantSharma - did you actually read Peter's answer?  If so, read it again.

Comment: Bringing the page only when it is needed will increase the page fault rate I.e. Pure demand paging. So there is no particular method to bring in the certain required pages on advance but only bring then when they are required (this will increase the page fault rate)

Answer (score 1):

Pager doesn't guess anything before the process is allocated the CPU. As soon as the process comes in running state, some of its pages will be loaded in main memory, and after that demand paging will come in picture, pages will be swapped out/in according to the demand of process.